# Position 3 div boxes side-by-side below a wider single div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get 3 divs to all be side by side below another div (that contains a h1 and a piece of small text below it). I'm having some trouble doing it.

What I am aiming for is something like this:
[image]

I've tried to put a div (that encompasses the 3 other divs) below the main title div.

I've tried this CSS:

```
.content-info {
    text-align: center;
    font-family:'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    top: 80%;
    left: 50%;
    text-align:center;
}
/* this is for the 3 divs to set width, etc*/
.content-info div {
    width:300px;
    padding:25px;
    margin: 25px;
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle of what I've got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/4zx9gxgL/

Any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4zx9gxgL/3/ i updated your fiddle - does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to go about this. CSS `table`, `float` and `position` offer three possible solutions. Depending on your overall objectives, here's a solution featuring `inline-block` (no `table`, no `float`, no `position`). This solution is very simple, stable, responsive, and easy-to-customize.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/nayztL4y/2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>H1 Header</h1>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="boxes"><h2>Box 1</h2></div>
    <div class="boxes"><h2>Box 2</h2></div>
    <div class="boxes"><h2>Box 3</h2></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 90%;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ff0;
}

.boxes {
    width: 25%;
    height: 180px;
    border: 2px dashed red;
    margin: 8px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**UPDATE**
I've updated your fiddle demo, as well.
http://jsfiddle.net/4zx9gxgL/33/

Comment: This is also great, how would I place them in the center?

Comment: I've updated your fiddle demo. Everything centers precisely and responsively with the help (again) of `inline-block`. http://jsfiddle.net/4zx9gxgL/33/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell` to make it work similar to a table.

For example:

```
.content-info {
    text-align: center;
    font-family:'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    display: table-row;
}
.content-info div {
    width:300px;
    padding:25px;
    margin: 25px;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

And you can remove the `.one{}`, `.two{}`, `.three{}` in your css

Comment: No problems.  Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.content-info {
    text-align: center;
    font-family:'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    top: 80%;
    left: 50%;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
/* this is for the 3 divs to set width, etc*/
.content-info div {
    width:300px;
    padding:25px;
    margin: 25px;
    float:left;
}
```

If the 3 bottom divs don't align correctly remove the margin settings, or adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

so you want to put all thre divs side by side. i think it's that .

```
 .main-content {
   text-align: center;
font-family:'Montserrat', sans-serif;
position: relative;


}
.content-info {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 110px;
top: 0px;
 }

 .yo{

 display: inline-block;
 width: 33%;
  margin-right: -2px;
  text-align:center;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4zx9gxgL/30/

Answer (score 0):

I had a go aswell ...

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
 body {
  background: url("http://pre15.deviantart.net/52ce/th/pre/i/2011/174/b/c/candy_blur_abstract_hd_by_ivereor-d3jsglw.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.yx {
  text-align: center;
}
.main-content {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: -100px;
  /* bring your own prefixes*/
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.main-content h1 {
  font-size: 62px;
}
.main-content h2 {
  font-size: 32px;
}
.content-info {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.content-info div {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 25px;
}
.one {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 33%;
}
.two {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 33%;
}
.three {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main-content yx">
    <h1>Name Here</h1>

    <h2>Hi, I'm Name.</h2>

  </div>
  <div class="content-info">
    <div class="one">
      <h3>BORAT IPSUM</h3>

      <p>This is my country of Kazakhstan. It locate between Tajikistan, and Kyrgyzstan, and assholes Uzbekistan.. What's up with it, vanilla face? Me and my homie Azamat just parked our slab outside. We're looking for somewhere to post up our black asses
        for the night. So, uh, bang bang, skeet skeet, nigga. Just a couple of pimps, no hoes..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      <h3>BORAT IPSUM</h3>

      <p>This is my country of Kazakhstan. It locate between Tajikistan, and Kyrgyzstan, and assholes Uzbekistan.. What's up with it, vanilla face? Me and my homie Azamat just parked our slab outside. We're looking for somewhere to post up our black asses
        for the night. So, uh, bang bang, skeet skeet, nigga. Just a couple of pimps, no hoes..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="three">
      <h3>BORAT IPSUM</h3>

      <p>This is my country of Kazakhstan. It locate between Tajikistan, and Kyrgyzstan, and assholes Uzbekistan.. What's up with it, vanilla face? Me and my homie Azamat just parked our slab outside. We're looking for somewhere to post up our black asses
        for the night. So, uh, bang bang, skeet skeet, nigga. Just a couple of pimps, no hoes..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
```